# When a checkbox is unchecked I want to show all data from the database

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to make a search with checkboxes. It works when the checkboxes are selected but does not show anything when unchecked. I want to show all the data from database when the checkbox is unchecked

```
$single = isset($_REQUEST['single']) ? 'Single' : '';
$married = isset($_REQUEST['married']) ? 'Married' : '';

SELECT *
FROM $users_table
WHERE (civil_status = '$single' OR civil_status = '$married')

<input type="checkbox" name = "single">
<label class="label-for-checkbox" >Single</label>
<input type="checkbox" name = "married">
<label class="label-for-checkbox" >Married</label>
```

In the database there is a column named 'civil status' which has ENUM value 'Single', 'Married'.

There are 2 checkboxes married and single. When I select married checkbox only list of people who are married displays. When I select single only list of single people displays. When both are selected it displays both results. But, when both of them are unchecked I want to show all married and single people.

Comment: You need to include all of the code relating to the issue, including the code relating to the checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

```
You need to attach your query on form submit :

$query = "SELECT * FROM `table_name'";

if(isset($_POST['single']))
    $query .= "where 'relationship_status' = 'S' or";
if(isset($_POST['married']))
    $query .= "where 'relationship_status' = 'M'";
```

If there are more conditions you can attach condition like above.

```
Manage the or and and accordingly according as per your requirement.
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use a way to build your sql with and without the various options. An easiest way is to use an array with `implode()`:

```
$opts = [];

if(isset($_REQUEST['single']))
    $opts[] = "civil_status = 'Single'";

if(isset($_REQUEST['married']))
    $opts[] = "civil_status = 'Married'";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM {$users_table}";

if(!empty($opts))
    $sql .= " WHERE (".implode(" OR ", $opts).")";
```

If you have nothing selected, it will then write:

```
SELECT * FROM {$users_table}
```

If you have one thing selected, it would write:

```
SELECT * FROM {$users_table} WHERE (civil_status = 'Married')
```

If both are selected:

```
SELECT * FROM {$users_table} WHERE (civil_status = 'Married' OR civil_status = 'Single')
```